# Google Script to Upload Folder from Desktop

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I've been searching around and can't seem to find what I'm trying to do. Not sure if it's even possible, but I'm looking for a Google Script that would probably run on a time-based trigger, say everyday at 4:00am that will grab a single folder from the users Desktop computer and automatically back it up to the Drive.

Is something like this possible? Can GAS access files that are located on a users computer, not just on their Google Drive?

Thanks in advance. 
Sean.

Comment: no it cant. impossible with apps script even if you were to leave open a webapp

Comment: As ZigMandel said it, impossible just with GAS, there's plenty of folder synchronization tools tough, Google Drive oficial one would work just fine to synchronize the whole desktop.

Comment: There's a decent overview of what [Google Apps Script Can't Do](http://www.steegle.com/google-products/google-apps-script-faq#TOC-What-can-Apps-Script-do-) posted on steegle.com. Not comprehensive, but better than anything I've seen in the offical docs.

Comment: Thank you Mogsdad, that was a perfect explanation of what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to do with scripts, but you might want to look into http://www.duplicati.com/

It's open source and works well for one-way upload (ie. backup)

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it will be to use the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/folder).
You can choose from may languages in order to implement it.

Comment: What i'm trying to do is have a script automatically upload a file from the users computer, for example from their root directory, or perhaps their actual Desktop. From the previous comments I don't believe this is possible.